# Codeigniter JOIN var_dump() showing strange outputs

Tags: activerecord, join, codeigniter-2

I am trying to JOIN two tables `customers` and `loan`. So my model is:

```
if($type == 'society'):
        $this->db->select('customers.customer_id,customers.customer_name,customers.customer_address,loan.loan_amount,loan.grant_date');
        $this->db->from('customers');
        $this->db->join('loan','loan.customer_id = customers.customer_id');
        $this->db->where('loan.customer_type',$type);
        $result = $this->db->get();
        endif;

        return $result;
```

And the controller :

```
$loan_customers_society = $this->loan_transaction_model->show_all_loan_customers($type = 'society');
var_dump($loan_customers_society);
```

But the output is something like below:

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)[19]
  public 'conn_id' => resource(36, mysql link persistent)
  public 'result_id' => resource(40, mysql result)
  public 'result_array' => 
    array
      empty
  public 'result_object' => 
    array
      empty
  public 'custom_result_object' => 
    array
      empty
  public 'current_row' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => int 3
  public 'row_data' => null
```

What this output is for? And how will I get my desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CI ActiveRecord `get()` method doesn't return the query result, it produces the query and returns the CI result object.

In order to get the result, you need to use `result()` or `result_array()` methods:

```
$query  = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();

// var_dump($result);
```

Take a look at *[Generating Query Results](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)* in CI user guide for more info.